# How parsing works for unix commands: "rm" and "cp"

Tags: bash, unix, wildcard, cp, rm

We are executing below commands

```
rm -f $folder_name/filename*

cp $folder_name1/filename1* $folder_name/
```

After checking the execution log we get following command executions

```
rm -f '/home/user/file*'

cp /home1/user1/file1* /home/user/
```

Why `rm` executes with a single quote and not `cp` command?

Comment: Wildcard expansion (and other option processing) is done by `bash` (or other shell), not `cp`/`rm`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chances are you are examining the output of `bash -x` which adds single quotes around arguments just for disambiguation. But the code you are showing could not result in the output you describe.

```
rm wildcard*
```

will expand to `rm` and the matching files if the wildcard has matches.  If it *doesn't*, though, the expansion will be the equivalent of

```
'rm' 'wildcard*'
```

where I have added quotes just to indicate that no further evaluation will take place, similary to what `bash -x` (and at least some variants of `sh -x`) does.